# Gradle marks errors in UI, but builds just fine

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-studio-3.0

[image: Screenshot from Android Studio]

> <*interface declaration*>, <*parcelable declaration*>, AidlTokenType.import or AidlTokenType.package expected, got 'com'

That is the exact *error message on hovering*.

<s>It **does not** have any side effects (app works/builds completely fine), but it is annoying and I could not get it back to normal. I am running *Android Studio 3.0 Canary 4* and the file is the `build.gradle` for the `app` module. All occurrences have the same error messages (replace "com" with "*" and "libs").</s>

How do I make those markers go away, what is the problem here?

#### Additional

**Un-inject Language/Reference** does not change anything.

The shown lines/symbols are the only affected in the whole project and I cannot remember when this error first started appearing, but it was not with the *Android Studio update*.

## Even stranger

When I implemented another library the same app level buildscript marks an error that a library version inside two different compiles would have a different version and so the build would fail, but it does not. And it stills unnecessarily marks *com*, *** and *libs* with the error message from above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was definitely fixed in some official version prior to April 2018.